# How i create diff. list_filters for superuser and staff user

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In admin i want to display diff. list_filter for superuser and staff user. How it possible.

When superuser is logged in:

```
list_filter = ('is_active', 'membership_type', 'is_blocked')
```

and for staff user with limited permission list_filters should be:

```
list_filter = ('is_active',)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this method to Admin class

```
def get_list_filter(self, request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return ('is_active', 'membership_type', 'is_blocked')
    return ('is_active',)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution of above problem. I change list_filters in changelist_view function.

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        self.list_filter = ('is_active', 'membership_type', 'is_blocked')
    else:
        self.list_filter = ('is_active',)
    return super(CustomUserAdmin, self).changelist_view(request)
```